# How can I change the folder where VLC stores its streams?

Tags: vlc, streaming

Stream records of `VLC` (by pressing the red "record" button) are stored in **~/Downloads/**.

[image: vlc record]

Can this be canged, and how? I couldn't find this option in settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try tools/preferences/ and ensure you have the "simple" interface selected. Press the "input & codecs" icon and you can specify the streaming location by setting "record directory or file name".